# Don't see webpage at http://localhost:8080/greeting

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a project with structure:

[image]

`build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'accouting'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

`Application.java`

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

`GreetingController.java`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Get your greeting <a href="/greeting">here</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`application.properties`

```
#Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.42:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
datasource.mine.poolSize=30

# Hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

`greeting.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

I don't see webpage at `http://localhost:8080/greeting`, how to fix it?

Comment: Off-topic. But can i know what sts is this.... <3

Comment: @Jay Spring Tool Suite is a customized version of Eclipse designed for Spring Application developers.

Comment: @DoNhuVy It appears you building a war file.  Are you deploying it to Tomcat?  Do the logs indicate the application started successfully?  Share a snippet if you can.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka I know, and I use sts myself. But this UI is simply <3

Comment: @punkrocker27ka this is log when run on Tomcat: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/f5188e1ce308326f5a3dbf079456d02d

Comment: @DoNhuVy Thanks.  I've provided an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40441065/1078565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GreetingController is in another package.  Move it to `com.example` and that should solve your problem.

If you still want keep package structure, use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hello")` and we have:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hello")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```